# Creating a size changing image in output cell

Tags: front-end, image-processing, notebooks, image

In the following video, there are `Image 1` and `Image 2`.

[image]

The image size of `Image 1` changes according to the notebook magnification. But `Image 2` does not.

Also you see both `Image 1` and `Image 2` are in input cell.

In other words, I've succeeded in creating two images with different properties **in input cell.**

Now I want to see an image like `Image 1`, in output cell.

Can you make an image which changes its image size according to notebook magnification **in an output cell** ?

I upload the .nb in the video  : [OkOk.nb](https://easyupload.io/f6s8x2)

To download the file, after clicking the link, just click Download (not TurboDownload.)

+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-

The flower image in the video is from mathematica tutorial, but I don't remember what exactly the tutorial is. But I can produce the same phenomenon easily, see the next video :

[Reproduce the video GIF](https://freeimage.host/i/ttt.HOh5p0F)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem neither in `"12.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 24, 2021)"` nor in `"13.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"`. Both images scale the same if I open your notebook. Can you please include instructions on how you prepared those two images? It might also be version-specific, happening (only) in 13.1.

Comment: Thank you, I checked again with 12.2 v and 13.1 v in windows 10 x64 in the same PC. And the result is the same.

Comment: And I added video how to reproduce it.