# The ultimate output control method

Tags: front-end, evaluation, output-formatting, expression-manipulation, cells

The ultimate substance of all matter is the atom, likewise,
the ultimate substance of mathematica cell is the **cell expression**,
and it can be obtained easily.

[image]

After copying the cell expression, and paste it then we see following popup :

[image]

Here, if I click yes, a cell with **the cell expression(=copied a minute ago)** is created.
(If click no, a cell of plain texts(=copied a minute ago) is created)

In fact the plain text of the cell expression is

```
Cell[BoxData[blahblah], ...]
```

And executing the following code is **almost equivalent** to pasting the copied cell exression and clicking yes.

```
ToExpression[BoxData[blahblah]]
```

What I want to say is from now on. It is **almost equivalent, but not 100% equivalent.**

For example, I experienced that

the copied cell expression for a certain cell with a certain image was

```
Cell[BoxData[GraphicsBox[blahblah, ... ,  BaseStyle -> "ImageGraphics" , ...]],...]
```

For this cell(=a certain cell with a certain image), let's first try **copy cell expression and paste method**.
Then I get 100% the same cell. In other words, the cell is duplicated exactly.

Now let's try **ToExpression[BoxData[.. method**.
Execute

```
 ToExpression[BoxData[GraphicsBox[blahblah, ... ,  BaseStyle -> "ImageGraphics" , ...]]]
```

then the output cell created isn't the same as the original cell. To be specific, one of the option part

```
 BaseStyle -> "ImageGraphics"
```

is changed to

```
 DefaultBasicStyle -> "ImageGraphics"
```

The change isn't small.
Because if that part is changed, the image size (the size we see by eyes) doesn't vary according to notebook magnification.
(If you would like to know more about this issue please refer to the following link :
[Creating a size changing image in output cell](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/283207/creating-a-size-changing-image-in-output-cell))

ToExpression generally works well but not in 100% manner.
**Copy cell expression and paste method** is 100% method but difficult to implement in code and cumbersome even if implemented.

Can we create a function, that works 100% exactly like **copy cell expression and paste method**?

`WithThisCellExpression[...]`

`NextCellShouldBeExactly[...]`

`UltimateOutputControl[...]`

`DirectCellWrite[...]`

It will be a revolution at least for me.

Comment: Checking `ClipboardNotebook` and `NotebookWrite` may be helpful.

Comment: Thank you, At present, I can set the cell expression (the plain text string) of any  cell that I want as a variable, say `var1`, with some codes. In that respect, I think the role of `ClipboardNotebook` is almost over at that stage.

Comment: I should find a way to way to create a cell with the exact cell expression. Hope `NotebookWrite` can do it but after seeing examples the tutorial of `NotebookWrite`, `NotebookWrite` doesn't seem to have ability to create a cell with given cell expression.

Comment: "[T]he ultimate substance ... is the cell expression"?? Not hardly. Hint: cells are meaningless in mathkernel. What's common across the program is the expression; that's the base unit.

Comment: I think there is an ultimate aspect in that I can make/decorate output whatever I want (complex table, grid, very complex nested matrix with nest fractions..).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`CellPrint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellPrint.html) together with [`NotebookRead`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookRead.html).

For example, the following code will reproduce the first cell from the notebook:

```
CellPrint[NotebookRead[First[Cells[]]]]
```

Comment: Wow, it worked! `CellPrint` is ultimate in some sense! Better then `ToExpression`.