# Notebook magnification - two independent values

Tags: functions, front-end, notebooks, image, system

It seems there are two **independent, equally influential** values those control mathematica notebook magnification.
Just like *volume bars* in a certain media player(program) and volume bar in tray bar(right side of windows 10 taskbar).

**One is** the following, the familiar one. :

[image]

We can get the value by

```
 CurrentValue[Magnification]
 1.25 (1.25 means 125%)
```

(Note that if you see 125% in the lower-right corner of mathematica but the value isn't 1.25, you might have already touched on the more unfamiliar things that will be explained next.)

But I do not know how to change the value by executing a code. <- This is the **first question.**

**The other** **is** less familar.
By default, the value is 1. You can change the value by executing the code

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, Magnification -> 1.3] (* 130% *)
```

But I do not know how to identify(=figure out) the value. <- This is the **second question.**

If we set these two values to 125% and 1.3, then the final magnification becomes 1.25*1.3 = 1.625.

Note that it seems neither the two values can change the final size(we see by our eye) in **image in output cell**.
See : [Creating a size changing image in output cell](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/283207/creating-a-size-changing-image-in-output-cell)

Comment: Try: `FrontEndExecute[SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, Magnification -> 1.5]]`

Comment: Thank you, but the effect of your code is the same as `SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, Magnification -> 1.5]` which is already mentioned in the original post. You can read my question more carefully!

Comment: Technically, there a 'N' values.  Global, `Notebook`, `Cell`, and the `Box` level settings.   Just experiment with multiple, nested `Style`s.  `Style[{"aaa", Style["bbb", Magnification -> .5 * Inherited], "ccc"}, 
 Magnification -> 6]`

Comment: Thank you for similar method for `Style` !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of them belongs to the whole front-end (session) and will affect all open notebooks, the other belongs to a particular notebook. Read more about option hierarchy in [@Mr. Wizard's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72990/75628).

Use [`CurrentValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CurrentValue.html) or [`Options`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Options.html) to get the value, and [`CurrentValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CurrentValue.html) or [`SetOptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetOptions.html) to set the value. Read more about this in the [Tutorial on Manipulating Notebooks](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ManipulatingNotebooks.html).

```
(* Get *)
CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, Magnification]
Options[$FrontEndSession, Magnification]

CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], Magnification]
Options[EvaluationNotebook[], Magnification]

(* Set *)
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, Magnification -> 2]
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Magnification -> 2]

CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, Magnification] = 2
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], Magnification] = 2
```

Note that you can also use `CurrentValue[Magnification]` because *`CurrentValue` by default refers to the location at which it appears in a notebook structure.*

Moreover, `Magnification` can also be set for a particular `Cell`.

```
(* Get *)
Options[First@Cells[], Magnification]
CurrentValue[First@Cells[], Magnification]

(* Set *)
SetOptions[First@Cells[], Magnification -> 2]
CurrentValue[First@Cells[], Magnification] = 2
```

Comment: For symmetries sake, it might be worth noting that `CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, Magnification] = 1.5` will also set the magnification, and `Options[$FrontEndSession, Magnification]` can also read out the current value

Comment: @LukasLang, thanks, I updated my answer! Too many different ways to obtain the same effect :)